# Sony Xperia J not showing up in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have a Sony Xperia J phone. I want to install and run android code in USB-debugging mode. I am using eclipse. Problem arises when the phone does not show up in the Android Device Chooser window which appears right after I hit the "run" button in eclipse. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Try downloading the correct driver for your phone from [here](http://developer.sonymobile.com/downloads/drivers/) or from [here](http://androidxda.com/download-sony-xperia-usb-driver). You should restart your computer after the install.

Answer (score 0):

After installing the drivers if you haven't  try this

Open Eclispe ->

Connect your Device ->

open DDMS perspective ->

From DDMS Reset ADB -> your Device will show up.